# Error occuring while using win32 in vs code (in python )

Tags: python

I am trying to convert text to speech in Python 3.10.2 using the code:

```py
import win32com.client
speaker = win32com.client.Dispatch("SAPI.SpVoice")
speaker.Speak("Hello, it works!")
```

But there is continuously occuring an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "d:\Program\Python programing\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 1, in <module>
    import win32com.client   File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py",
line 10, in <module>
    from . import dynamic   File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py",
line 24, in <module>
    from . import build   File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\win32com\client\build.py",
line 638, in <module>
    valid_identifier_chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + "_" AttributeError: module 'string' has no attribute 'ascii_letters'
```

Comment: Looking at the file name `programing\tempCodeRunnerFile.py`, it looks like you had some portion of your program selected when you ran the program using "Code Runner" extension. Did you try running it without the selection?

Comment: `import win32com.client speaker = win32com.client.Dispatch("SAPI.SpVoice") speaker.Speak("Hello, it works!")` Is it really one line in your actual code?

Comment: please insert your code and traceback as is without conversions. And use code block (`{ }` mark) instead of quote

Comment: Your traceback contains *AttributeError: module 'string' has no attribute 'ascii_letters'*.
This is weird, because the string module of the standard library does have this attribute. Could you have a custom module named `string`?

Comment: If you create a new .py file containing just these three lines, does it work? If not, the error is elsewhere in `tempCodeRunnerFile.py`.

Answer (score 1):

you wrote two lines of code in the same line
Try this

```
import win32com.client
speaker = win32com.client.Dispatch("SAPI.SpVoice")
speaker.Speak("Hello, it works!")
```

or try to put a semicolon after the first line of code
Try this

```
import win32com.client; speaker =win32com.client.Dispatch("SAPI.SpVoice")
speaker.Speak("Hello, it works!")
```

either way should work

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. I tried both ways that you recommend but it throws the same error as earlier.

Comment: While I write the code the.Speak() function is not highlighted

Comment: I just copied your code and did that small edit and that worked for me. I don't know the solution for sure but if I were you I would try to reinstall python, because it seems that the error is in importing the library.